# Migration Process in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

C:\xampp\htdocs\blog>php artisan migrate

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is
>   767 bytes (SQL: alter table `password_resets` add index
>   `password_resets_email_index`(`email`))

Comment: Hello I am New in Laravel php Kindly help me i faced the error which is mention above

Answer (score 1):

That's a character set problem (charset is `utf8mb4` since Laravel 5.4). Either make sure your database is `utf8mb4` or:

Edit your `AppServiceProvider.php` file and inside the boot method set a default string length:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: ya i edited but again but now it shows the error    (Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found)

Comment: I edited the question, added the "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;" line, sorry, forgot that.